# SSH connection to Azure VM with Terraform

Tags: linux, azure, terraform

I have successfully created a VM as part of a Resource Group on Azure using Terraform. Next step is to ssh in the new machine and run a few commands. For that, I have created a provisioner as part of the VM resource and set up an SSH connection:

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "helloterraformvm" {
    name = "terraformvm"
    location = "West US"
    resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.helloterraform.name}"
    network_interface_ids = ["${azurerm_network_interface.helloterraformnic.id}"]
    vm_size = "Standard_A0"

    storage_image_reference {
        publisher = "Canonical"
        offer = "UbuntuServer"
        sku = "14.04.2-LTS"
        version = "latest"
    }


    os_profile {
        computer_name = "hostname"
        user     = "some_user"
        password = "some_password"
    }

    os_profile_linux_config {
        disable_password_authentication = false
    }

    provisioner "remote-exec" {
        inline = [
          "sudo apt-get install docker.io -y"
        ]
        connection {
          type     = "ssh"
          user     = "some_user"
          password = "some_password"
        }
    }

}
```

If I run "terraform apply", it seems to get into an infinite loop trying to ssh unsuccessfully, repeating this log over and over:

```
azurerm_virtual_machine.helloterraformvm (remote-exec): Connecting to remote host via SSH...
azurerm_virtual_machine.helloterraformvm (remote-exec):   Host:
azurerm_virtual_machine.helloterraformvm (remote-exec):   User: testadmin
azurerm_virtual_machine.helloterraformvm (remote-exec):   Password: true
azurerm_virtual_machine.helloterraformvm (remote-exec):   Private key: false
azurerm_virtual_machine.helloterraformvm (remote-exec):   SSH Agent: true
```

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, but I don't know what it is :(

EDIT:

I have tried setting up this machine without the provisioner, and I can SSH to it no problems with the given username/passwd. However I need to look up the host name in the Azure portal because I don't know how to retrieve it from Terraform. It's suspicious that the "Host:" line in the log is empty, so I wonder if it has anything to do with that?

UPDATE:

I've tried with different things like indicating the host name in the connection with

```
host = "${azurerm_public_ip.helloterraformip.id}"
```

and

```
host = "${azurerm_public_ip.helloterraformips.ip_address}"
```

as indicated in the docs, but with no success.

I've also tried using ssh-keys instead of password, but same result - infinite loop of connection tries, with no clear error message as of why it's not connecting.

Comment: Can you manually ssh into that box with those credentials?

Comment: right, my bad, you didn't have a "create NSG" step, so no need to create rules for that.

Comment: @evilSnobu Yes, I can manually ssh into the machine with the user/passwd combination. I have updated the question with that information.

Comment: @zapatilla I check your question, based on my understanding, you want to docker when you create a VM. For a Azure VM, you don't need ssh to it. You could use Azure Custom Script Extension to do this. terraform support the extension. I test it, it works fine for me. You could check my answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have managed to make this work. I changed several things:

- Gave name of host to `connection`.
- Configured SSH keys properly - they need to be unencrypted.
- Took the `connection` element out of the `provisioner` element.

Here's the full working Terraform file, replacing the data like SSH keys, etc.:

```
# Configure Azure provider
provider "azurerm" {
  subscription_id = "${var.azure_subscription_id}"
  client_id       = "${var.azure_client_id}"
  client_secret   = "${var.azure_client_secret}"
  tenant_id       = "${var.azure_tenant_id}"
}

# create a resource group if it doesn't exist
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
    name = "sometestrg"
    location = "ukwest"
}

# create virtual network
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {
    name = "tfvnet"
    address_space = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
    location = "ukwest"
    resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg.name}"
}

# create subnet
resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnet" {
    name = "tfsub"
    resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg.name}"
    virtual_network_name = "${azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name}"
    address_prefix = "10.0.2.0/24"
    #network_security_group_id = "${azurerm_network_security_group.nsg.id}"
}

# create public IPs
resource "azurerm_public_ip" "ip" {
    name = "tfip"
    location = "ukwest"
    resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg.name}"
    public_ip_address_allocation = "dynamic"
    domain_name_label = "sometestdn"

    tags {
        environment = "staging"
    }
}

# create network interface
resource "azurerm_network_interface" "ni" {
    name = "tfni"
    location = "ukwest"
    resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg.name}"

    ip_configuration {
        name = "ipconfiguration"
        subnet_id = "${azurerm_subnet.subnet.id}"
        private_ip_address_allocation = "static"
        private_ip_address = "10.0.2.5"
        public_ip_address_id = "${azurerm_public_ip.ip.id}"
    }
}

# create storage account
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "storage" {
    name = "someteststorage"
    resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg.name}"
    location = "ukwest"
    account_type = "Standard_LRS"

    tags {
        environment = "staging"
    }
}

# create storage container
resource "azurerm_storage_container" "storagecont" {
    name = "vhd"
    resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg.name}"
    storage_account_name = "${azurerm_storage_account.storage.name}"
    container_access_type = "private"
    depends_on = ["azurerm_storage_account.storage"]
}



# create virtual machine
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "vm" {
    name = "sometestvm"
    location = "ukwest"
    resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg.name}"
    network_interface_ids = ["${azurerm_network_interface.ni.id}"]
    vm_size = "Standard_A0"

    storage_image_reference {
        publisher = "Canonical"
        offer = "UbuntuServer"
        sku = "16.04-LTS"
        version = "latest"
    }

    storage_os_disk {
        name = "myosdisk"
        vhd_uri = "${azurerm_storage_account.storage.primary_blob_endpoint}${azurerm_storage_container.storagecont.name}/myosdisk.vhd"
        caching = "ReadWrite"
        create_option = "FromImage"
    }

    os_profile {
        computer_name = "testhost"
        admin_username = "testuser"
        admin_password = "Password123"
    }

    os_profile_linux_config {
      disable_password_authentication = false
      ssh_keys = [{
        path     = "/home/testuser/.ssh/authorized_keys"
        key_data = "ssh-rsa xxx email@something.com"
      }]
    }

    connection {
        host = "sometestdn.ukwest.cloudapp.azure.com"
        user = "testuser"
        type = "ssh"
        private_key = "${file("~/.ssh/id_rsa_unencrypted")}"
        timeout = "1m"
        agent = true
    }

    provisioner "remote-exec" {
        inline = [
          "sudo apt-get update",
          "sudo apt-get install docker.io -y",
          "git clone https://github.com/somepublicrepo.git",
          "cd Docker-sample",
          "sudo docker build -t mywebapp .",
          "sudo docker run -d -p 5000:5000 mywebapp"
        ]
    }

    tags {
        environment = "staging"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

According to your description, [Azure Custom Script Extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/extensions-customscript) is an option for you.

> The Custom Script Extension downloads and executes scripts on Azure
>   virtual machines. This extension is useful for post deployment
>   configuration, software installation, or any other configuration /
>   management task.

Remove `provisioner "remote-exec"` instead of below:

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "helloterraformvm" {
  name                 = "hostname"
  location             = "West US"
  resource_group_name  = "${azurerm_resource_group.helloterraformvm.name}"
  virtual_machine_name = "${azurerm_virtual_machine.helloterraformvm.name}"
  publisher            = "Microsoft.OSTCExtensions"
  type                 = "CustomScriptForLinux"
  type_handler_version = "1.2"

  settings = <<SETTINGS
    {
        "commandToExecute": "apt-get install docker.io -y"
    }
SETTINGS
}
```

Note: Command is executed by root user, don't use `sudo`.

More information please refer to this link: [azurerm_virtual_machine_extension](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/virtual_machine_extension.html).

For a list of possible extensions, you can use the Azure CLI command `az vm extension image list -o table`

Update: The above example only supports single command. If you need to multiple commands. Like install docker on your VM, you need

```
apt-get update 
apt-get install docker.io -y
```

Save it as a file named script.sh and save it to Azure Storage account or GitHub(The file should be public). Modify terraform file like below:

```
 settings = <<SETTINGS
    {
        "fileUris": ["https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Walter-Shui/dedb53f71da126a179544c91d267cdce/raw/bb3e4d90e3291530570eca6f4ff7981fdcab695c/script.sh"],
        "commandToExecute": "sh script.sh"
    }
SETTINGS
```

Comment: Hi Walter - MSFT. I managed to make Terraform provisioner work using SSH keys. I'll publish my working example tomorrow. What is from your alternative that is better than Terraform provisioner? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @zapatilla For a Azure VM, this is a better alternative. Because Azure install an agent on Linux VM . `Custom script extension` uses the agent to execute scripts on your VM, you don't need ssh to your VM.

Comment: @zapatilla I think it is a easy for you to achieve your need. If possible, you could test.

Comment: I have tried it for now command and it seems to work. This is great because it doesn't require sending SSH keys as my initial alternative. However the scripts that I need to run are not oneliners nor should they be saved on GH as public. I'm going to try to automate saving the script on Azure Storage and see how it goes. Thanks again for the suggestion!

Comment: There's something else I'm not sure I like - the extension doesn't output the standard output of the commands I'm running on the VM, whereas the other solution does. Also it takes much longer which in my case is important. I think it's a good alternative, but I'm going to use the other one.

Comment: @zapatilla Thanks for your reply. `connection` works on all VMs, `Custom Script extension` only works for Azure VMs.