# Unable to execute custom data in azure VM from terraform

Tags: powershell, azure, terraform

I'm trying to create azure vm using terraform . But unable to execute custom data  from terraform. Customdata.bin file is created on server .
Also tried provisioner resource but no luck .

main.tf file  azure vm resource syntax :

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "avmweb0" {
  name                  = "${var.env}-${var.bu}-${var.company_name}-media-vm"
  location              = "${var.region}"
  resource_group_name   = "${module.network.resource-grp-name}"
  network_interface_ids = ["${azurerm_network_interface.nicweb0.id}"]
  vm_size               = "${var.vm_size}"


  storage_image_reference {
    publisher       = "${var.vm_publisher}"
    offer           = "${var.vm_offer}"
    sku             = "${var.vm_sku}"
    version         = "${var.vm_version}"

  }

  storage_os_disk {
    name              = "${var.env}-${var.bu}-${var.company_name}-media-osdisk"
    caching           = "ReadWrite"
    create_option     = "FromImage"
    managed_disk_type = "Standard_LRS"
  }



  os_profile {
    computer_name  = "${var.env}-${var.vm_computer_name}"
    admin_username = "${var.vm_admin_username}"
    admin_password = "${var.vm_admin_password}"
    custom_data    = "${data.template_file.userdata.rendered}" 
  }

   os_profile_windows_config{
     winrm {
       protocol="http"
     }

    }

   /* 
     connection {
      type     = "winrm"
      user     = "${var.vm_admin_username}"
      password = "${var.vm_admin_password}"
      host     = "${azurerm_public_ip.mediapubip.ip_address}"
      port     = 5985
      https    = false
      insecure = true
      timeout      = "15m"
      # cacert       = ""
    } */

   /* provisioner "file" {
    content      = "${data.template_file.userdata.rendered}"
    destination = "C:\\AzureData\\initdata.ps1"

    connection {
      type     = "winrm"
      user     = "${var.vm_admin_username}"
      password = "${var.vm_admin_password}"
    }
  }
   provisioner "remote-exec" {


    inline = [ "powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -NoProfile -NonInteractive -File \"C:\\AzureData\\initdata.ps1\""]


  }  */

  /* provisioner "file" {
    content      = "${data.template_file.userdata.rendered}"
    destination = "C:\\AzureData\\initdata.ps1"
  }

   provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -File \"C:\\AzureData\\initdata.ps1\" -NoProfile -NonInteractive "
  } */

  tags {
        Name            = "${var.env}-${var.bu}-${var.company_name}-media"
        BussinessUnit   = "${var.bu}"
        Environment     = "${var.env}"
        CompanyName     = "${var.company_name}"
        Application     = "${var.appname}"
   }
}
```

------------custom data file ---------------------------------

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy unrestricted
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="http" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=80

write-host "running init script"
if(!(test-path -Path "c:\temp"))
  {    
    New-Item -ItemType directory -Path "C:\temp"
    write-host "created temp directory"
  }
$client = new-object System.Net.WebClient
$client.DownloadFile("https://downloads.puppetlabs.com/windows/puppet5/puppet-agent-5.0.0-x64.msi","c:\temp\puppet.msi")
cd "c:\temp"
pwd
echo "`nx.x.x.x puppet"  | Out-File -FilePath "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts" -Append -Encoding ascii
msiexec /qn /norestart /i "c:\temp\puppet.msi" 
if(test-path -path "C:\ProgramData\PuppetLabs\facter\facts.d")
  {
    echo "`nhello"  | Out-File -FilePath "C:\ProgramData\PuppetLabs\facter\facts.d\facts.yaml" -Encoding ascii
    echo "`nconsolename : ${consolename}" | Out-File -FilePath "C:\ProgramData\PuppetLabs\facter\facts.d\facts.yaml" -Append -Encoding ascii
    echo "`nbu : ${bu}" | Out-File -FilePath "C:\ProgramData\PuppetLabs\facter\facts.d\facts.yaml" -Append -Encoding ascii
    echo "`nenv : ${env}" | Out-File -FilePath "C:\ProgramData\PuppetLabs\facter\facts.d\facts.yaml" -Append -Encoding ascii            
    echo "`ncompany_name : ${company_name}" | Out-File -FilePath "C:\ProgramData\PuppetLabs\facter\facts.d\facts.yaml" -Append -Encoding ascii
    echo "`napplication : ${application}" |  Out-File -FilePath "C:\ProgramData\PuppetLabs\facter\facts.d\facts.yaml" -Append -Encoding ascii
    echo "`nservertype : ${servertype}" |  Out-File -FilePath "C:\ProgramData\PuppetLabs\facter\facts.d\facts.yaml" -Append -Encoding ascii
 }
```

Error when using provisioner resource :
1 error(s) occurred:

- azurerm_virtual_machine.avmweb0: 1 error(s) occurred:
- unknown error Post http://x.x.x.x:5985/wsman: dial tcp x.x.x.x:5985: connectex: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

Terraform does not automatically rollback in the face of errors.
Instead, your Terraform state file has been partially updated with
any resources that successfully completed. Please address the error
above and apply again to incrementally change your infrastructure.[0m[0m

code :

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "avmme0" {
  name                 = "${var.env}-${var.vm_computer_name}-config"
  location             = "West US"
  resource_group_name  = "${module.network.resource-grp-name}"
  virtual_machine_name = "${azurerm_virtual_machine.avmweb0.name}"
  publisher            = "Microsoft.Compute"
  type                 = "CustomScriptExtension"
  type_handler_version = "1.8"

  settings = <<SETTINGS
    {
        "fileUris": ["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/saveshnshetty/devops/master/userdata.ps1"],
        "commandToExecute": "powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -NoProfile -NonInteractive -File userdata.ps1"
    }
SETTINGS

  tags {
        Name            = "${var.env}-${var.bu}-${var.company_name}-media"
        BussinessUnit   = "${var.bu}"
        Environment     = "${var.env}"
        CompanyName     = "${var.company_name}"
        Application     = "${var.appname}"
   }
}
```

error :
[0m[1mazurerm_virtual_machine_extension.avmme0: Still creating... (25m20s elapsed)[0m[0m
[31mError applying plan:

1 error(s) occurred:

- azurerm_virtual_machine_extension.avmme0: 1 error(s) occurred:
- azurerm_virtual_machine_extension.avmme0: compute.VirtualMachineExtensionsClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=200 -- Original Error: Long running operation terminated with status 'Failed': Code="VMAgentStatusCommunicationError" Message="VM 'dev-it-mactores-media-vm' has not reported status for VM agent or extensions. Please verify the VM has a running VM agent, and can establish outbound connections to Azure storage."

I'm able to download from server with below commands :
$client = new-object System.Net.WebClient
$client.DownloadFile("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/saveshnshetty/devops/master/userdata.ps1","c:\temp\userdata.ps1")

Inbound  and outbound rule is open for 5985 .

```
Tf var file  details :
region                  ="West US"
storage_account_type    =""
vm.size                 ="Standard_DS1_v2"
location                ="West US"
appname                 ="xxx"
bu                      ="it"
company_name            ="xxxx"
env                     ="dev"
tenant_id               =""
client_secret           =""
client_id               =""
storage_account_type    ="Standard_LRS"
vm_size                 = "Standard_DS1_v2"
vm_publisher            = "MicrosoftWindowsServer"
vm_offer                = "WindowsServer"
vm_sku                  = "2012-R2-Datacenter"
vm_version              = "latest"
vm_computer_name        = "web-media"
vm_admin_username       = "xxxx"
vm_admin_password       = "xxxx"
```

Comment: So what's the problem? There's a wall of code and config, but no errors or description what happens and what is supposed to happen.

Comment: It's not throwing any error from terraform side when i run only custom data script in azure vm resource . But it's throw error when i execute provisioner resource .

Comment: Please edit the question and add the error details in the question itself. Don't add them as comments.

Comment: @sarveshshetty You could use Azure Custom Script Extension to do this,please refer to my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the error log is you don't open port 5985 on Azure NSG. So, your script could not connect to Azure VM.  For a Azure VM, I suggest you could use [`Custom Script Extension`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/extensions-customscript) instead `winrm` your VM.

> The Custom Script Extension downloads and executes scripts on Azure
>   virtual machines. This extension is useful for post deployment
>   configuration, software installation, or any other configuration /
>   management task.

Terraform also support custom script extension. Please refer to this [link](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/virtual_machine_extension.html). According to your scenario, I suggest you save your custom data as a ps1 file and upload it to GitHub or Azure storage account. You could refer to my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44997257/ssh-connection-to-azure-vm-with-terraform/45002859#45002859). Windows Custom Script extension should use like below:

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "test" {
  name                 = "hostname"
  location             = "West US"
  resource_group_name  = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.name}"
  virtual_machine_name = "${azurerm_virtual_machine.test.name}"
  publisher            = "Microsoft.Compute"
  type                 = "CustomScriptExtension"
  type_handler_version = "1.8"

   settings = <<SETTINGS
    {
        "fileUris": ["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/saveshnshetty/devops/master/userdata.ps1"],
        "commandToExecute": "powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -NoProfile -NonInteractive -File userdata.ps1"
    }
SETTINGS
```

You could check my [vm.tf](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Walter-Shui/9f3088ac2e7b82766f4380f60419578d/raw/f9bbc0aefc21c4776690e8a9548926bca6bed537/vm.tf).

Comment: Thanks Walter!!  I tried  custom extension script and  calling *.ps1 file in custom data script  but no luck !!

Comment: @sarveshshetty This is your own VHD image and Azure image? I will test in my lab.

Comment: added above in question .

Comment: This is azure image

Comment: added tf var file details above .

Comment: @sarveshshetty You could RDP to your VM and suggest extension log path is `C:\WindowsAzure\Logs\Plugins\Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension`

Comment: There is no  folder C:\WindowsAzure in  C drive .

Comment: @sarveshshetty The log path is `C:\WindowsAzure\Logs\Plugins\Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension\1.8`

Comment: @sarveshshetty Your Powershell script works for me. You could check my [vm.tf](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Walter-Shui/9f3088ac2e7b82766f4380f60419578d/raw/f9bbc0aefc21c4776690e8a9548926bca6bed537/vm.tf).

Comment: Thanks Walter !! Can you share security groups details .

Comment: my sg grp :  allowed inbound port 3389 ,5985.  outbound port 80 ,443,5985,8140

Comment: Sorry, I don't create NSG, I think the port is enough. If you use Azure Custom extension, don't need open port 5985.

Comment: Thanks Walter !! Appreciate your help .I'm creating  new OS disk  without vhd will this impact ?

Comment: If possible, I suggest you could use my vm.tf to create a VM. According to your extension log, it seems that Azure does not install on the VM, but I am not sure.

Comment: Walter, can you  please share your OS disk vhd url .I can use that and update you about result .

Comment: @sarveshshetty You could check this `vhd_uri       = "${azurerm_storage_account.test.primary_blob_endpoint}${azurerm_storage_container.test.name}/myosdisk1.vhd"`

Comment: @sarveshshetty In your tf file. `storage_os_disk` lose `vhd_uri` Please check this https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/virtual_machine.html

Comment: Thanks Walter!!!  I'll update and run my code . Thanks Again for your quick  response !!!!

Comment: Yes Walter Finally it worked !!...  I've removed all outbound rules.